# SQL - Assess minimum value across multiple rows, then filter to show list of unique rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My end goal is to create a list of honor roll students. Each student has multiple rows, one for each grade. I want to say, look at their grades across these rows; only show 1 student name if none of their grades are <80%.

I've started just with this, but I'm stuck, I don't know how to assess across the multiple rows as a criterion for  selecting a unique list.

```
SELECT students.first_name, students.last_name, storedgrades.storecode, storedgrades.percent,storedgrades.course_name
FROM storedgrades join
     students
     on students.ID = storedgrades.StudentID
where students.enroll_status=0  AND
      storedgrades.termid>2799  AND
      storedgrades.storecode = 'Q4'
```

Example of grades table:

```
BOB  A  95
BOB D  65
ANDREA  B  85
ANDREA  A  95
```

EXAMPLE RESULT:

```
ANDREA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation.  I think this is what you want:

```
select s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
from students s join
     storedgrades sg 
     on s.ID = sg.StudentID
where s.enroll_status = 0  and
      sg.termid > 2799  AND
      sg.storecode = 'Q4'
group by s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
having count(*) = 5 and  -- you want all five courses
       min(scorecode) >= 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a distinct list of student names, then compare with a NOT EXISTS to the grades table where the grade is less than 80%

```
SELECT distinct students.ID, students.first_name, students.last_name
FROM storedgrades s join
     students
     on students.ID = storedgrades.StudentID
where students.enroll_status=0  AND
      storedgrades.termid>2799  AND
      storedgrades.storecode = 'Q4' and not exists
      (select 'x' from storedgrades s2 where s2.students.StudentID = s.StudentID and s2.first_name = s.first_name and 
s.last_name = s2.last_name and s2.percent < 80)
```

EDIT: added in studentID to the join

Comment: Thank you! I'll revisit this when I get a little more skilled. The other answer using group by is getting this done for me.